# AWS APIGateway lambda authorizer caching policy even after setting ttl to zero

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using an APIGateway lambda Authorizer with the following policy generation code but seems like even after setting the time to live on the authorizer lambda to zero still the policy is getting cached for some reason.

- The caching behavior is random.
- I have set the time to leave to zero because I want the authorizer to be called for each and every request.

This is my code:

```
var generatePolicy = function(principalId, effect, resource) {
    var authResponse = {};

    authResponse.principalId = principalId;
    if (effect && resource) {
        var policyDocument = {};
        policyDocument.Version = '2012-10-17'; 
        policyDocument.Statement = [];
        var statementOne = {};
        statementOne.Action = 'execute-api:Invoke'; 
        statementOne.Effect = effect;
        statementOne.Resource = resource.replace(/:function:.+$/, ':function:*');
        policyDocument.Statement[0] = statementOne;
        authResponse.policyDocument = policyDocument;
    }

    authResponse.context = {
        "stringKey": "stringval",
        "numberKey": 123,
        "booleanKey": true
        };
        return authResponse;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @oocilec want the authorizer to be invoked each time, hence the ttl is set to zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Try changing the  `statementOne.Resource = '*';` this will work.
- For a valid policy, API Gateway caches the returned policy, associated with the incoming token or identity source request parameters.

Comment: Isn't that overly permissive? It would mean any API in the account can be invoked.

Comment: This doesnt really solve the underlying issue. Would result in some potential security concerns like overly permissive resource permissions, and if the authorizer is still caching, the authorizer could potentially grant access to an api even with an expired authorization token.